# Add New Functionality on Overridden Module

Tags: configuration

Currently, I am trying to add new functionality whereby customize the City field from text to select in edit address book page. I made this change on my own module (path: local/Company/NewDirectory) and result is working fine at the frontend.

Then, I decided to move this functionality to overridden module. However, I am confused in defining the class prefix in the config.xml for this functionality.

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_Directory>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Company_Directory>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <directory>
            <!-- I have an overriden class at here -->
            <rewrite>
                <data>Company_Directory_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </directory>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <directory>
            <!-- How to define this class prefix without overwrite the Mage's ? -->
            <class>Company_Directory_Model</class> 
            <resourceModel>directory_resource</resourceModel>
        </directory>
        <directory_resource>
            <!-- How to define this class prefix without overwrite the Mage's ? -->
            <class>Company_Directory_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <region_city>
                    <table>directory_region_city</table>
                </region_city>
            </entities>
        </directory_resource>
    </models>
    ...
</global></config>
```

Comment: Which models/helpers you want to override?

Comment: I managed to override Mage_Directory_Helper_Data class, but confusing on how to define the class prefix in above config.xml for my new model classes.

Answer (score 0):

As general best practise use you module name('directory) plus your namespace(company) -> company_directory. Let's say you have a model named Calculation(located in app/code/**code_pool**/Company/Directory/Model/Calculation.php. Than in your code use Mage::getModel('company_directory/calculation'). Note the underscore before the slash doesn't get converted to location on the filesystem(it's just the value of the node in config.xml). Let's say you want to instantiate a helper : Mage::helper('company_directory/data') => Company_Directory_Helper_Data. Also take a look at this reference: http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/08/31/magento-module-configuration-file-reference.html

---

**EDIT**
I changed the config xml as below and combined with your proposed, now the functionality is working at frontend. But I am not sure whether these steps are best practice when adding new classes to overridden module. Hope someone here can give a friendly advice.

```
<models>
<company_directory>
    <class>Company_Directory_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>company_directory_resource</resourceModel>
</company_directory>
<company_directory_resource>
    <class>Company_Directory_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>
       <region_city>
           <table>directory_region_city</table>
       </region_city>
    </entities>
</company_directory_resource></models>
```

Comment: Pardon for my english. By given your example model class Calculation.php, is it that I no need to define the class name prefix in config.xml, instead just use Mage::getModel('company_directory/calculation') in my code?

Comment: Yes, here is the connection between config.xml and Mage::getModel() for example. In your case company_director->Company_Directory_Model(a file path). Take a look at this cheat sheet for another example: http://www.magentix.fr/assets/files/magento-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Take a look at these : http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/, http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part10-series-overriding

Comment: The model class was not found, error: "No such file or directory". And here is the stack trace:`#4 ..\Config.php(1346): class_exists('Mage_Company_D...')
#5 ..\Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('company_direct...', Array)
#6 ..\local\Company\Directory\Helper\Data.php(92): Mage::getModel('company_direct...')
#7 ..\template\customer\address\edit.phtml(177): Company_Directory_Helper_Data->getCityJson()`

Comment: Did you update your config.xml, so that it looks like this: <models>
        **<company_directory>**
            <!-- How to define this class prefix without overwrite the Mage's ? -->
            <class>Company_Directory_Model</class> 
            .....
    </models>

Comment: as you seen in stack #6, I coded like this 

`$collection = Mage::getModel('company_directory/city')->getResourceCollection()
 ->addRegionFilter($regionIds)
 ->load();` 

then see #4, somehow the class prefix "Mage" has been added.

Comment: Try to clear the cache

Comment: Afraid to say, if adding that to config.xml, it would be overwrite the core module class name prefix, causes core directory model classes could not be resolved =(

Comment: Ok, try to follow the process of rewriting a model/helper in the two articles in one of my previous comments. Here is another article that describes how to create a model in Magento:http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2009/10/magento-part-ii-models/

Comment: Evgeni, the overridden class is working fine, but not for new model classes under overridden module. Appreciate your efforts =)

Comment: I got that the last article is about creating a NEW (not  overriden) model. Also verify that this is correct: the class name of your City model is : app/code/code_pool/Company/Directory/Model/City.php and the class name is Company_Directory_Model_City.

Comment: Verified and it is correct `class Company_Directory_Model_City extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {` thanks for the article, im reading it